# Accessing web site inside a private network

Tags: node.js, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am currently developing a web site with node.js in a private LAN (company LAN):
`192.168.20.55`.
My webapp runs on port 3000, so if I want to see it, I go to my browser and type:
`192.168.20.55:3000`
And I can see my webapp without problems.
Now, this private LAN is firewalled: I cannot access from the outside with ssh (it shows connection timed out), the only way I can manage to work from the outside is making a reverse ssh tunnel that I get from here: https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling which basically says:
 
from company:
`ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 myhome@myhomeip`

And then from my home:

`ssh localhost -p 19999`

This way I can successfully access through ssh to my company server from home, but I just can not figure out how to see the webapp.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to open the `3000` port, because that's what your server is running on?

Comment: indeed. why forward port 19999 locally if you need a connection to port 3000?

Comment: is 192.168.20.55 the ip of your computer? if so, forward port 3000 instead of 22.

Answer (score 0):

I would give a try to SOCKS5 proxy. It is easy to set up and transparent. As you have set up reversed ssh tunnel, you can connect to your internal network using

```
ssh -p 19999 localhost
```

Adding `-D 9999`:

```
ssh -p 19999 -D 9999 localhost
```

will create you SOCKS5 proxy on `localhost:9999` using which you can access internal company network. You can set up most of the tools to use this proxy (Firefox).